# How to get a combination of keys in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

How can I capture <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> keys on a C# form?
thanks

Comment: Globally or just when the form has focus?

Answer (score 16):

It is a chord, you cannot detect it without memorizing having seen the first keystroke of the chord.  This works:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private bool prefixSeen;

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
        if (prefixSeen) {
            if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Control | Keys.P)) {
                MessageBox.Show("Got it!");
            }
            prefixSeen = false;
            return true;
        }
        if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.Control | Keys.K)) {
            prefixSeen = true;
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this capture repeating keys too? If a chord like CTRL + P + P is used for instance?

Comment: Repeating keys would produce Ctrl+P Ctrl+P.  So no.

Comment: I just compiled and tested the code, and it _does_ (incorrectly) captures repeating keys if the chord uses the same key twice. For instance, holding CTRL + ALT + P will trigger the CTRL + ALT + P + P chord.

Comment: Then you did it wrong, remove Keys.Alt and Keys.Control from the second if() statement.

Comment: What do you mean, I "did it wrong"? It's your code...  :-) I just replaced "Keys.K" with "Keys.P". And removing Alt and Control, as you suggested,  would block the key 'P' from being used at all in the form.

Comment: Oops, first if() statement.  Click the Ask Question button if you still have problems.

Comment: No, that won't work either. But that's not the point. This code will not work for some chords, and I wanted to point that out to other users.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if you can. What you CAN do however, is the way Visual Studio does it.
It has shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>. You first press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, then hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and press <kbd>C</kbd>. In your case, you could check for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>P</kbd>.

You can first check for only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as done in the other answers, then set a member variable/flag to indicate <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> has been pressed. In the same method where you check for <kbd>K</kbd> you can check for <kbd>P</kbd>, and if the flag you just set was set to true, do whatever you need to do. Otherwise set the flag back to false.

Rough pseudo-code:

```
private bool m_bCtrlAltKPressed = false;

public void KeyDown() {
  if (Ctrl+Alt+K)
  {
    m_bCtrlAltKPressed = true;
  }
  else if (Ctrl+Alt+P && m_bCtrlAltKPressed) {
    //do stuff
  }
  else {
    m_bCtrlAltKPressed = false;
  }
}
```

Hope that's clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

`MessageFilters` can help you in this case.

```
    public class KeystrokMessageFilter : System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter
    {
        public KeystrokMessageFilter() { }

        #region Implementation of IMessageFilter

        public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
        {
            if ((m.Msg == 256 /*0x0100*/))
            {
                switch (((int)m.WParam) | ((int)Control.ModifierKeys))
                {
                    case (int)(Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.K):
                        MessageBox.Show("You pressed ctrl + alt + k");
                        break;
                    //This does not work. It seems you can only check single character along with CTRL and ALT.
                    //case (int)(Keys.Control | Keys.Alt | Keys.K | Keys.P):
                    //    MessageBox.Show("You pressed ctrl + alt + k + p");
                    //    break;
                    case (int)(Keys.Control | Keys.C): MessageBox.Show("You pressed ctrl+c");
                        break;
                    case (int)(Keys.Control | Keys.V): MessageBox.Show("You pressed ctrl+v");
                        break;
                    case (int)Keys.Up: MessageBox.Show("You pressed up");
                        break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        #endregion


    }
```

Now in your C# WindowsForm, register the MessageFilter for capturing key-strokes and combinations.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    KeystrokMessageFilter keyStrokeMessageFilter = new KeystrokMessageFilter();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }       
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(keyStrokeMessageFilter);
    }
}
```

> Somehow it only detects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>. Please Read the comment in MessageFilter code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to get the status of the other keys when one of the keys in the combination has been pressed.  Here's an example on a form.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DetectKeyChord
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        private const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x80;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void ShortcutAction()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ctrl+Alt+K+P has been pressed.");
        }

        private bool IsKeyDown(Keys key)
        {
            return (NativeMethods.GetKeyState(key) & KEY_PRESSED) == KEY_PRESSED;
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                //If any of the keys in the chord have been pressed, check to see if
                //the entire chord is down.
                if (new[] { Keys.P, Keys.K, Keys.ControlKey, Keys.Menu }.Contains((Keys)m.WParam))
                {
                    if (IsKeyDown(Keys.ControlKey) && IsKeyDown(Keys.Menu) && IsKeyDown(Keys.K) && IsKeyDown(Keys.P))
                    {
                        this.ShortcutAction();
                    }
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
    }

    public static class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("USER32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetKeyState(Keys nVirtKey);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See this great blog post about setting up hotkeys in c#

- [Christian Liensberger » Blog »
  Installing a global hot key with
  C#](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207)

There's also a good article that explains all of this here

- [Simple steps to enable Hotkey and ShortcutInput user control - CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/ashsimplehotkeys.aspx)