# Visual Studio Shortcutkeys

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sdk, keyboard-shortcuts

I was working on a project, and while pressing some shortcut keys, I noticed the status bar of Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

Please try some shortcuts yourself to notice the whole behavior of VS, and then...how could I achieve that effect at the same level of performance? Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have the following code block taken from Stack Overlow, that does something like that but not the same performacnce level. My code works for <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey( ref Message msg, Keys keyData )
{
    if (prefixSeen)
    {
        if (keyData == ( Keys.Control | Keys.P))
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Got it!" );
            keyComb.Text = "Ready";
        }
        prefixSeen = false;
        return true;
    }
    if (keyData == ( Keys.Control | Keys.K))
    {
        prefixSeen = true;
        keyComb.Text = "CTRL + K was pressed. Waiting for a second chord of keys...";
        return true;
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey( ref msg, keyData );
}
```

But after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> The label `keyComb` does not take the value "CTRL + K was pressed. Waiting for a second chord of keys..."

Code taken from: [How to get a combination of keys in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Attribution is required at this site.

Comment: What do you mean with "attribution"? :-?

Comment: Click on the cc-wiki icon on the lower right of this page.

Comment: In fact, I don:t know where was this code taken from. It is true, that it was taken from StackOverfow, but I can't exactly remember the question....

Comment: Are you banned from Google?  Don't be helpless, type "prefixseen" in the search box at the upper right.

Comment: oh. now I got the idea. you are the author of that question =))

Comment: In fact, do you know something to help me, or not? :)