# Customizing menu shortcut keys

Tags: c#, string, menu, keyboard-shortcuts, customization

I am working on an application that has a Menu on top of it. I want to use a different method for shortcut keys (being this snippet): this is for shortcut key: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>

```
bool prefixSeen = false;

protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (prefixSeen)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case (Keys.Control | Keys.D1):
                MessageBox.Show("New file");
                prefixSeen = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    switch (keyData)
    {
        case (Keys.Control | Keys.n):
            prefixSeen = true;
        break;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp).

Here is my menu:

[image]

And I want in menu items to be displayed (aligned on the right) the shortcut key (that should just be interpreted as a string I think). How can I achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance, and a Happy New Year to every one.

**Edit:**  the built-in method for Visual Studio is:

[image]

Comment: `I want to use a different method for shortcut keys` -- this is built in (see Mark Hall's answer). Why use a different method?

Comment: @JonB, look at my edit (at my snippet) to see why I want to use custom shortcut keys listener.

Comment: You keep violating the attribution rule, even after it was **explicitly** pointed out to you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13459248/visual-studio-shortcutkeys

Comment: @HansPassant, that is my own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`MenuItem.ShortCut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.shortcut.aspx) and [`MenuItem.ShowShortCut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.showshortcut.aspx) Properties.

---

If you want to create your own custom shortcuts these properties will not work for you, since they depend on a predetermined enumeration of ShortCut Keys. In that case I would suggest that you add it to the Text of your Menu, there is no automatic way of doing it.

---

Since it was pointed out that you are using `ToolStripMenuItems` you should be able to independantly set the [`ShortCutKeyDisplayString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmenuitem.shortcutkeydisplaystring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to what every you wish. You will still need to handle the actual Shortcut yourself.

Comment: But how can I customize the Menu control to achieve that?

Comment: @Victor Are you using MenuItems or toolStripMenuItems?

Comment: I am using toolStripMenuItems