# How to fire both Shortcut Keys and KeyDown event? (C# Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, keydown

I have a `TextBox`'s KeyDown event that start a timer when it is called. I also have a Paste `MenuStripItem` and I set the ShorcutKeys property in Design View to `Ctrl + V`.

I notice that when user press the shortcut keys (`Ctrl + V`), the KeyDown event will not be called. And when I set the ShortcutKeys property to None, KeyDown is normally called. Is there a way to fire both event when I press the `Ctrl + V`?

**I has tried with other MenuStripItem and the result are the same.**

**EDIT:** Thank you very much, @Hans. When I move my code from KeyDown event to ProcessCmdKey, it works really well. (So I suppose the ProcessCmdKey is the method which is called everytime a key is pressed nomatter what it is). Because you deleted your previous anwser so I can't mark it as answer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void somethind_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (KeyCodes.Contains(e.KeyValue) || (e.KeyCode==Keys.V && e.Control))
        e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
    else 
        e.SuppressKeyPress=true;
}
```

See this list of keycodes: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

I hope this helps!

Comment: I mean when you set a shortcut keys to the menustripitem, and you press that shortcut keys, it will ignore the keydown event. I'm not ask about how to catch the Ctrl + V key in the keydown event

Comment: Might be because Ctrl+V is well embedded into the system itself.

Comment: Nah, It only ignore when you set the MenuStripItem's ShortcutKeys property.

Comment: I know that they ignore when you set the MenuStripItem's shortcut key action. However, either this is a new behavior or something has changed, are you on Windows 8.1? In addition, which Visual Studio and C# version do you run?

Comment: Yes, I use Windows 8.1, Visual Studio 13.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14104657/customizing-menu-shortcut-keys

Comment: I don't get your point. If it about handle the ShortCut key in the KeyDown event, it is very inconvenient, isn't it? Because I have to paste the code from MenuStripItem's Click event to the KeyDown event for every MenuStrip. I already thought about it, that's why I ask here to find another solution.

Comment: In what way is this *inconvenient*?

Comment: Well, I did a search through Google with nothing to really suggest other ways. Maybe everything requires a little bit of more hard coding. Just maybe.