# Implementing Multi-letter Hotkey

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, hotkeys

I would like to implement a hotkey that is similar to how visual studio implements some of their hotkeys, like the formatting one (CTRL + K + D). That is, one with multiple letters, in this case.

I am aware of how to do one with just one letter and modifier, and probably even two modifiers if I needed. But the multi-letter part seems to be throwing me off on how. Is there a easy way to do this? (WinForms is what I'm working with by the way.)

Currently, the only way I can think to do it is by having some static flag inside the event method for key-down and then setting it if the first key was pressed and then if the next key is correct have an if statement execute if the flag is set and the key is the correct key.

EDIT:
Another thread for this same question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3244286/3235548).

The general consensus seems to be that you need to have some sort of flag indicating that the previous key has already been pressed right before the next one. And then have corresponding `if` statements to do the appropriate actions.

Comment: This is from the back of my head: There are no multi letter key events. Not even on the bus level. If multiple (non-modifier) keys are pressed, they get sent as seperate interrupts thus they appear as seperate events. So you'll have to use flags. But in any case the additional problem is that some keyboards support sending multiple keypresses and some do not. And some do for specific keys only. (this is due to the limitations on the ciurcit boards of the keyboards themself) So using/allowing multi-letter hotkeys in your applications is unreliable at best.

Comment: About your only choice is to build a state machine, yeah.  Catch the keystrokes (but let them through unless you get a complete sequence hit) and maintain the previous stroke for comparison.

Comment: Yup, that's the same thing I'm asking. Dang it...my Google-Fu needs to improve. Thanks. @MrPaulch, ya, that seems to be what needs to happen (the setting of flags).