# How do I capture PrintScreen in a Hot Key Control in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, user-interface

I'm working on a screen capture program and I want to allow users to set custom hotkeys.

I have tried using the Windows `msctls_hotkey32` control class in a custom control using `CreateParams`. However, it doesn't accept <kbd>PrintScr</kbd> as key, which due to the nature of my program, is not acceptable.

I have tried making a custom control that extends `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` and overrides `ProcessCmdKey` to capture keyboard input. However, the function is never called for the PrintScreen key, and combinations involving the key don't include it (e.g. pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScr</kbd> only gives me `ControlKey, Control`).

After some research I found out that only a `WM_KEYUP` message is sent for PrintScreen, but for a hot key control, only the key down event is acceptable because you need to be able to enter key combinations.

Is there a workaround that allows me to capture key combinations that include PrintScreen? 
If not, how could I design my user interface to allow such key combinations without simply using a huge dropdown?

Comment: Windows already uses a hot key for the PrintScreen button.  Stealing it requires using a special id, IDHOT_SNAPDESKTOP (-2) and IDHOT_SNAPWINDOW (-1).  No idea how well that works on modern Windows version, I'd imagine that UAC elevation is required.  Teaching the hotkey control new tricks is a long shot, just make your own.

Comment: And that's what I've tried to do as well - extend a TextBox and override ProcessCmdKey to get the keyboard input, except it doesn't get called with PrintScr

Comment: Well, sure, chicken-and-egg problem of course :)  To see the key you first have to register the hotkey.  Just doing it temporarily, while your textbox has the focus, shouldn't be a hangup.

Comment: In screen capture program keyboard focus will be in some other window when user presses `PrintScr`. You have to use *keyboard hook* (google for it) and this approach should save the problem of catching `PrintScr` from within your window as well.

Comment: @AndrewLambert I already use it in the actual screen capture functionality, though I suppose I could re-use it in the settings form and manually set the control that has the focus when I get a callback from the hotkey... It's not ideal but I suppose it's one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref Message msg) {
if (((Keys)(int)msg.WParam) == Keys.PrintScreen) {
  ScreenCapture(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
  }
  return base.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref msg);
}
```

more info [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39197/Print-Screen-in-C)

Upd:

```
protected override bool ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref Message msg) {
  Keys keyData = (Keys)msg.WParam | ModifierKeys;
  if (keyData  == (Keys.PrintScreen | Keys.Control)) {
    ScreenCapture(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));
  }
  return base.ProcessKeyEventArgs(ref msg);
}
```

Comment: This too only gives me PrintScreen on WM_KEYUP and not on WM_KEYDOWN, so I can't determine key combinations.

Comment: in this case you should use protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) {
       if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.PrintScr)) {
          // do PrintScreen
       }
       return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

Comment: here describe it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp

Comment: I'm already using ProcessCmdKey and it doesn't work, as I've stated in the question

Comment: I don't think there's much to see, but the current version is at https://github.com/horsedrowner/Superscrot/blob/hotkey-config/Superscrot.Controls/HotkeyInput.cs#L148

Comment: @horsedrowner Why on earth you use `ProcessCmdKey`? It is for controls with `ContextMenu`! Did you even try the codes from @AlexFilatov and @user3311691 to catch the `PrintScreen` key? The code you have in the link shows that you didn't try anything.

Comment: The code in the link doesn't show I tried anything because generally you don't commit code that doesn't work to version control

Answer (score 0):

I would first capture the `WM_KEYDOWN` message and check the `virtual key code`:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{

    if (m.Msg == 0x0100) //WM_KEYDOWN
    {
        if ((int)m.WParam == 0x2C) //VK_SNAPSHOT
        {
            //...
        }
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

But as in your case as in my it doesn't work. That is because my keyboard(probably yours too) for the `PrintScr` it uses the `Insert` key instead. So, changing

```
(int)m.WParam == 0x2C //VK_SNAPSHOT
```

to

```
(int)m.WParam == 0x2D //VK_INSERT
```

solved the problem

Comment: If I print the key code in WndProc and I press PrintScr, I only get a WM_KEYUP message, never a WM_KEYDOWN message, not even for a different key