# Is there a way to do a multiple part keyboard shortcut with ToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have been able to do shortcuts with modifiers (keys.Control + keys.Shift + Keys.Q, for example), but I was wondering if there was a way to do a shortcut that had multiple steps, for example Keys.Control + keys.K, then Keys.Contol + keys.D.

Comment: In VS at least, that's called a chord.  There's nothing built into Windows Forms to support it specifically so you'd just have to handle keyboard events and remember the partial chords yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3244063/how-to-get-a-combination-of-keys-in-c-sharp/3244286#3244286

Comment: Why is VS able to this and we don't get that feature implemented in .NET? :(

Comment: Is there some requirement that every feature of VS is also implemented in the Framework that I wasn't aware of?